# How to use data from one HTML page to retrieve data to be used on another HTML page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I would like to use the 'sID' in the first HTML form to retrieve data from the database and then use the data retrieved from the database on the second HTML page. I can do this with just php, but I just can't figure out how to do it using ajax.

I'm really new to javascript/ajax so please be gentle with your answers :)

### HTML 1

```
            <div class="moreR">             
                 <form action="moreR_2.0.php" method="GET">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sID[]" value="a_certain_ID"/>
                   <input type="image" src="Icons/PNG/greater_than.png" alt="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
```

---

### PHP (moreR_2.0.php)

```
<?php
        include ('session_start.php');        
        include ('db_connect_mO.php');

    if (isset($_GET['sID'])) {
        foreach($_GET['sID'] as $sID) { 
            }
}

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mo WHERE sID=$sID");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 

        {           
            $test[]= array( 
                            'pZero'=> $row['pZero'],
                            'pZero_Gname'=> $row['gZero_key'],  
                        );
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode ($test);

        //detailed error reporting
        if (!$sql) 
        {
            echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db);
        exit;

        }
?>
```

---

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    "use strict"; 

    function connect2mR() { 

    $.ajax({
        url:"moreR_2.0.php",
        type: "GET",
        data:'sID',
        dataType:"json",
        //async:false,
        success:function(data)
        {    
            $('#pZero').html('<img src="rPlanets/' + this.gZero + '.png" alt=""/>');
            $('#pZero_keys').html(this.gZero_key);
        }, //success


    }); //end of ajax

    } //end of function

    if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', connect2mR);}
    else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load',     connect2mR, false);}
    else {document.addEventListener('load', connect2mR, false);}

    });
```

---

### HTML 2

```
<section class="moreR_section">
    <div style="width:20%;"><div id="pZero"></div></div>
    <div class="moreR_g" style="margin-left:26%" id="pZero_keys"></div>
</section>
```

What i'm trying to do is; start from HTML 1, collect sID -> then PHP/JS use sID from HTML 1 to get data from database -> then use the result from database on HTML 2. At the moment i'm struggling on how to make this process work. Can't figure out how to start from HTML 1 and end up in HTML 2.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(data)` in the success on the ajax call?

Comment: i don't get anything, its almost like it isn't communicating with the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching the data from the input element at all.. change your ajax code to below.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"moreR_2.0.php",
    type: "GET",
    data:{sID: $('input[name="sID[]"]').val()},  // this is the change
    dataType:"json",
    //async:false,
    success:function(data)
    {    
        $('#pZero').html('<img src="rPlanets/' + this.gZero + '.png" alt=""/>');
        $('#pZero_keys').html(this.gZero_key);
    }, //success


}); //end of ajax
```

**Edit 1:** you can use `localstorage` to save data and retrieve from there when ever required. So you can do as below

In your HTML 1 write this.

```
localStorage.setItem('sID', JSON.stringify( $('input[name="sID[]"]').val()));
```

And in HTML 2 you can access the value by reading it from the local storage like below,

```
var sIDofHTML1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sID'));
```

Comment: how can I make 'HTML 1' to run the JAVASCRIPT for HTML 2 and  then go to HTML 2?

Comment: You need to load html2 by using Ajax.  And then run any scripts on it

Comment: Thanks @Reddy, but how can I do this?

Comment: I thought your Ajax is already loading your html2... What is the purpose of your Ajax??

Comment: Yes. So I have first_page.html (HTML 1), then I have second_page.html (HTML 2). The javascript here is for the second_page.html. I don't know how to use the 'sID' from first_page.html and then go to second_page.html which will load the javascript and use the 'sID' from first_page.html to retrieve data from database via ajax and php. and show result in second_page.html..

Comment: @chiboz Oh got you. You can just save the first page data into a local storage, it would be in the browser or you can use cookies and then read from there in your second page.

Comment: Thanks @Reddy for answer, however when i redirect to HTML 2 from HTML 1 nothing happens (blank screen) unless refresh the page then it works. Any suggestion on how to fix this will really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @chiboz I don't know what code you are using to redirect to HTML2 and why it is blank, I answered your question `How to use data from one HTML page to retrieve data to be used on another HTML page using ajax` and you don't even care to say if it works for you or not. And what ever you are asking is completely different question. You can ask a new question by posting this problem and adding required code.

Comment: my thanking you for your answer was to acknowledge that your code did do what you said it would, I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. The only change to my previous code apart from adding yours was changing the action="moreR_2.0.php" to action="moreR_2.0.html" (html 2) which does the re-directing and I apologize for not saying that earlier. Thanks again for help

Comment: @chiboz glad to hear your issue is fixed, happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the `ajax` as below.

```
data:'sID',  // this has to change to data:'sID='+sID,


$.ajax({
    url:"moreR_2.0.php",
    type: "GET",
    data:'sID',  // this has to change to data:'sID='+sID,
    dataType:"json",
    //async:false,
    success:function(data)
    {    
        $('#pZero').html('<img src="rPlanets/' + this.gZero + '.png" alt=""/>');
        $('#pZero_keys').html(this.gZero_key);
    }, //success


}); //end of ajax
```